# Possible? if ($(this:first-child).is("element")) - Using selectors with $(this)

Tags: jquery

It's pretty easy for me to get this going and it works:

```
if ($(this).next().is("object")){//dostuff}
```

But due to new div containments i now have to check the first child of *this*. 
But $(this) doesn't play nice with selectors, how do i do the same kind of thing in that situ?

This doesn't work:

```
  if ($(this:first-child).is("element"))
```

Comment: I doubt that that works, since it's not even valid Javascript.

Comment: Uhm, it totally does. And it's jQuery, not JS.

Comment: You do realize jQuery is a library written *in JavaScript*

Comment: No, the second block totally is not valid JavaScript. jQuery is written in JavaScript ;)

Comment: @RGBK: (a) No, you have a very obvious syntax error. (b) jQuery is a library written in Javascript, not some separate language. You're still writing Javascript, using jQuery functions (which mostly start with a call to the function `$`).

Comment: lol, of course i do! And hold on, the second block doesnt work, the first does. Thanks.

Comment: @RGBK: Your "not JS" statement would indicate that you do not. And the first block still is _not valid_.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HPxw2/2/ Dunno what to say. Yes there was a missing . between the next() and is() but thats been corrected.

Comment: @RGBK: Yes, so now it is correct (though your testcase still has the `}` commented out). I'm trying to train you to think analytically and _precisely_, but it doesn't seem to be working very well.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, you are ultimately right :-) And i do sincerely appreciate all your input thus far. Cheers.

Comment: @RGBK: Please use `@` notification syntax; I stumbled upon your comment reply only by chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean it "doesn't play nice"? You don't write `:first-child` outside of a string for any other selector, so why would you with `this`?

Stack selectors on `$(this)` like you would on any other jQuery object:

```
$(this).find(':first-child').is("element");
```

or:

```
$(':first-child', this).is("element");
```

There may be more effective solutions for this specific scenario, but my answer demonstrates how to use `$(this)` like any other jQuery object.